# What is the optimal weight ratio for a multistage water rocket?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, rocketry

I do know about the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation for optimising multistage rockets, however the equation requires a fixed exhaust velocity which is something that water rockets don't have, so for this purpose is there another method of calulating the optimal ratio or just use the average exhaust velocity over the entire burntime?

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be better suited to SE Space Exploration.

Comment: So what are you asking? the optimum ratio? or another method of calculation?